# Boot from USB and run batch file

Tags: usb, boot, batch, mount

I'm trying to boot from USB and run a batch file that will mount the computer's main hard drive and will copy a file from the root directory into a specified directory on the computer's hard drive.

I have searched and searched the internet. I have found nothing that can aid me.

I originally tried to use www.nu2.nu's tools to make a bootable msdos disk that would automatically run a batch. It worked. But I forgot to make it mount the main HDD. So, in essence, nothing was done.

I used www.nu2.nu's tool to make an iso. I then used YUMI multiboot utility (google it) to make my USB bootable. Everything went fine. Just nothing was accomplished (as said above).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Plain MS-DOS won't work with NTFS. I suppose this could be done using a WinPE or Linux based LiveUSB.

Comment: Also, IF it is an NTFS drive from Win Vista or Win7, there are probably ACLs in place, so if you want to (re-)place a file on a system or user owned, private folder, just by mounting a drive it won't work.

Comment: Like @Karan mentioned I always use winPE for things like this. UBCD for win on a usb stick is my go to as long as the machine is 32 bit. If it is 64 bit I would suggest the latest version of the Unbuntu Live CD. If you are unfamiliar with linux and bash there are hundreds of tutorials to show you how to mount drives and move files, if they did not automagically mount; which in newer versions of Unbuntu is rare.